# R loop/lapply, cumulative totals with group by

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, cumsum, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create new variables in my data set that are cumulative totals which restart based on other variables (using group by)… I want these to be new columns in the data set and this is the part I am struggling with...

Using the data below, I want to create cumulative Sale and Profit columns that will restart for every Product and Product_Cat grouping.

The below code partly gives me what I need, but the variables are not new variables, instead it overwrites the existing Sale/Profit... what am I getting wrong? I imagine this is simple haven't found anything.

Note: I'm using lapply as my real data set has 40+ varbs that I need to create calculations for.

```
DT <- setDT(Data)[,lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = .(Product,Product_Cat) ]
```

Data for example:

```
Product <- c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C')
Product_Cat <- c('S1','S1','S2','C1','C1','C1','D1','E1','F1')
Sale <- c(10,15,5,20,15,10,5,5,5)
Profit <- c(2,4,2,6,8,2,4,6,8)
Sale_Cum <- c(10,25,5,20,35,45,5,5,5)
Profit_Cum <- c(2,6,2,6,14,16,4,6,8)

Data <- data.frame(Product,Product_Cat,Sale,Profit)
Desired_Data <- data.frame(Product,Product_Cat,Sale,Profit,Sale_Cum,Profit_Cum)
```

Comment: i just wanna say, the rhythmic lilt of this title makes me happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)

cols <- names(Data)[3:4]

Data[, paste0(cols, '_cumsum') := lapply(.SD, cumsum)
     , by = .(Product, Product_Cat) 
     , .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: Thanks - this is simple and EXACTLY what I was looking for - easy to repeat across 40+ columns too. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, perhaps this is a separate post... but what if I wanted the cumsum to be the cumulative total minus the current value? In this case, the first cumsum for each value would be 0... the Sale_cumsum for line 6 (B, C1) would be 35 instead of 45. Does that make sense and can it be done?

Comment: change `lapply(.SD, cumsum)` to `lapply(.SD, function(x) cumsum(x) - x)` in that case

Comment: Perfect - this worked. I can't thank you enough! Saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't use the group by per se but I think it achieves what you're looking for in that it is easily extensible to many columns:

```
D2 <- data.frame(lapply(Data[,c(3,4)], cumsum))
names(D2) <- gsub("$", "_cum", names(Data[,c(3,4)]))
Data <- cbind(Data, D2)
```

If you have 40+ columns just change the c(3,4) to include all the columns you're after.

EDIT:

I forgot that the OP wanted it to reset for each category. In that case, you can modify your original code:

```
DT <- setDT(Data)[,lapply(.SD, cumsum), by = .(Product,Product_Cat) ]
names(D2)[c(-1,-2)] <- gsub("$", "_cum", names(Data)[c(-1,-2)])
cbind(Data, D2[,c(-1,-2)])
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be restarting with each new `Product_Cat` (first three values of `Sales_Cum` are 10, 25, 30, and they should be 10, 25, 5)

Comment: you're right!  See the revised solution which uses some of the code from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
structure(list(Product = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Product_Cat = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("C1", "D1", "E1", 
"F1", "S1", "S2"), class = "factor"), Sale = c(10L, 15L, 5L, 
20L, 15L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Profit = c(2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 
4L, 6L, 8L), Sale_Cum = c(10, 25, 5, 20, 35, 45, 5, 5, 5), Profit_Cum = c(2, 
6, 2, 6, 14, 16, 4, 6, 8)), .Names = c("Product", "Product_Cat", 
"Sale", "Profit", "Sale_Cum", "Profit_Cum"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")`
```

We can iteratively slice the dataframe based on `Product` and `Product_Cat`, and for each iteration, assign the output produced by `cumsum()` to `Sale_Cum` and `Product_Cum`:

```
cols <- c('Sale', 'Profit')

for (column in cols){
  x[, paste0(column, '_Cum')] <- 0
  for(p in unique(x$Product)){
    for (pc in unique(x$Product_Cat)){
      x[x$Product == p & x$Product_Cat == pc, paste0(column, '_Cum')] <- cumsum(x[x$Product == p & x$Product_Cat == pc, column])
    }
  }
}
print(x)
# Product Product_Cat Sale Profit Sale_Cum Profit_Cum
# 1       A          S1   10      2       10          2
# 2       A          S1   15      4       25          6
# 3       A          S2    5      2        5          2
# 4       B          C1   20      6       20          6
# 5       B          C1   15      8       35         14
# 6       B          C1   10      2       45         16
# 7       C          D1    5      4        5          4
# 8       C          E1    5      6        5          6
# 9       C          F1    5      8        5          8
```

Comment: This might work, but I'm trying to avoid having to write out a calculation for each variable... my real data set has 40+ variables I would need to calculate cumulative totals for, which is why I went with the lapply approach.

Comment: Edited. Nothing a triple-nested for loop can't solve!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pretty poor code that does everything step by step

```
#sample data
d<-sample(1:10)
f<-sample(1:10)
p<-c("f","f","f","f","q","q","q","w","w","w")
pc<-c("c","c","d","d","d","v","v","v","b","b")
cc<-data.table(p,pc,d,f)

#storing the values that are overwritten first.
three<-cc[,3]
four<- cc[,4]
#applying your function 
dt<-setDT(c)[,lapply(.SD,cumsum), by=.(p,pc)]

#binding the stored values to your function and renaming everything.
x<-cbind(dt,three,four)
colnames(x)[5]<-"sale"
colnames(x)[6]<-"profit"
colnames(x)[4]<-"CumSale"
colnames(x)[3]<-"CumProfit"

#reordering the columns
xx<-x[,c("p","pc","profit","sale","CumSale","CumProfit")]
xx
```